# Sympy Segment intersection order dependent

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, intersection

I have the following code which when executed returns an empty list. However, when I reverse the first and second points in `b`, I get the right output.

*Input:*

```
from sympy import Segment3D, Point3D
a = Segment3D(Point3D(315250, -96200, 107500), Point3D(315250, -96200, 114500))
b = Segment3D(Point3D(315250, -96200, 107500), Point3D(315250, -96200, 105500))
a.intersection(b)
```

*Output:*

```
[]
```

*Input*

```
from sympy import Segment3D, Point3D
a = Segment3D(Point3D(315250, -96200, 107500), Point3D(315250, -96200, 114500))
b = Segment3D(Point3D(315250, -96200, 105500),Point3D(315250, -96200, 107500))
a.intersection(b)
```

*Output:*

```
[Point3D(315250, -96200, 107500)]
```

Is this a bug? How do I resolve it?

Comment: In SymPy 1.3, both give the same result.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference for others, I was using version 1.1.1